# Displaying a range of cells

Tags: vba

I have different values in range c18:z18
I could able to find the maximum number in this range by;

```
Dim MX as double
MX = worksheetfunction.max (sheets("sheet4").range ("c18:z18"))
```

I want to copy three cells just above the maximum cell (mx) and paste them in sheet1 then display them in message box as a result.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The code you've currently given us doesn't attempt to do anything that you describe, it just finds the max value. Try using the `.Find` method against the range and then with the `.Offset` you can get the 3 cells above it...

Comment: Cells.find (what:="MX", after:=activecell, lookin:=xp values, lookat:=xlwhole, searchorder:=xlbycol‌​umns, searchdirection:=xln‌​ext, matchcase:=false, searchformat:=false)‌​.activate

Comment: above command doesn't function. I wanted to activate the cell of the maximum value and tan move up wars to select the above cells. But I could not Manage to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim MX as double, rng as range

Set rng = sheets("sheet4").range ("c18:z18")
MX = worksheetfunction.max (sheets("sheet4").range ("c18:z18"))

'where is the max value ?
Debug.Print rng.cells(application.match(MX, rng, 0)).address
```

To get the above 3 cells:

```
Debug.Print rng.Cells(Application.Match(MX,rng,False)).Offset(-3).Resize(3).Address
```

If you remove the `.Address` you can `.Select` it (though that's generally to be avoided)

```
rng.Cells(Application.Match(MX,rng,False)).Offset(-3).Resize(3).Select
```

Etc.

Comment: Thank you, i wrote the following code but it doesn't Function

Comment: Cells.find (wha:="MX", after:=activecell, lookin:=xp values,  lookat:=xlwhole, searchorder:=xlbycolumns, searchdirection:=xlnext, matchcase:=false, searchformat:=false).activate

Comment: `wha` is not a parameter name for Find(). Did you try the approach I posted above?

Comment: Yes but debug doesn't function

Comment: What happens when you run the code - do you get an error?

Comment: Debug.print rng.cells (application.match (MX,rng,0)).adress ()

Comment: This line is highlited in yellow

Comment: When i delete the adres() part at the end of The command i get the maximum value as a result

Comment: I could able to Manage it i get the cell address with your code now.thank you so much.

Comment: See revision to my answer